# Problems with test Redis cache with @MockBean

Tags: java, testing, caching, redis, mocking

I'm trying to test an implementation of cache with redis and when I debug, I could check the repository is null and I don't know if it's ok with it.

[image]

But the test fails:
INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils -- Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [com.example.pocredis.cache.AnyObjectCachingIntegrationTest]: AnyObjectCachingIntegrationTest does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended

Wanted but not invoked:
com.example.pocredis.repository.AnyObjectRepository#0 bean.findById(
1L
);
-> at com.example.pocredis.cache.AnyObjectCachingIntegrationTest.verify_findById_cache_interaction_with_repository(AnyObjectCachingIntegrationTest.java:52)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Wanted but not invoked:
com.example.pocredis.repository.AnyObjectRepository#0 bean.findById(
1L
);
-> at com.example.pocredis.cache.AnyObjectCachingIntegrationTest.verify_findById_cache_interaction_with_repository(AnyObjectCachingIntegrationTest.java:52)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

```
at com.example.pocredis.cache.AnyObjectCachingIntegrationTest.verify_findById_cache_interaction_with_repository(AnyObjectCachingIntegrationTest.java:52)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
```

Process finished with exit code -1

Config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class RedisCacheConfig {

    @Bean
    public RedisCacheManager cacheManager(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        RedisCacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
            .entryTtl(Duration.ofMinutes(10))
            .disableCachingNullValues();

        return RedisCacheManager.builder(connectionFactory)
                .cacheDefaults(cacheConfiguration)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public HashKey hashKey() {
        return new HashKey();
    }
}
```

Service class:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AnyObjectService {

    private final AnyObjectRepository repository;

    @Cacheable(value = "anyObjects", key = "#id")
    public AnyObject findById(Long id) {
        return repository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new AnyObjectNotFoundException(id));
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
@Import({ RedisCacheConfig.class, AnyObjectService.class})
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@EnableCaching
@ImportAutoConfiguration(classes = {
        CacheAutoConfiguration.class,
        RedisAutoConfiguration.class
})
public class AnyObjectCachingIntegrationTest {

    @MockBean
    private AnyObjectRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    private AnyObjectService service;

    @Autowired
    private CacheManager cacheManager;


    @Test
    void verify_findById_cache_interaction_with_repository() {
        AnyObject obj = createValidAnyObject();

        when(repository.findById(obj.getId())).thenReturn(Optional.of(obj));

        service.findById(obj.getId());
        service.findById(obj.getId());

        verify(repository, times(1)).findById(obj.getId());
    }
}
```